# How quickly does the message from BroadcastManager get to the listeners on Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I perform:

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I am wondering how quickly this broadcast gets picked up by the listeners?  Is it in miliseconds? or something longer/shorter?

Comment: Depends on many factors like hwd speed,  load level etc,  but if you need for speed don't expect broadcast to be speed daemons...

Comment: Agreed. It will also depend upon which listeners have/do not have processes running.

Comment: I am using a LocalBroadcastManager and things seemed pretty speedy for me.  I am calling it ~5x per second